# How to number the data based 2 set of rules (Date and Type)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, sorting

I am creating a database where different numbers will be assigned to each row based on 2 parameters.

1. Date
2. Manager Name

[image: Sample dataset here]

As shown in the image based on the consultant and the date of booking, the booking id should change.

So e.g if there are 4 entries for ryan on 09/07/2020, the booking ids should be Ryan-09/07-1,Ryan-09/07-2,Ryan-09/07-3,Ryan-09/07-4 and for ryan's booking on 10/07/2020 the booking id should be Ryan-10/07-1 and so on.

I tried using countif but doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula.

I used `Table` with structured references, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer.

**With Structured referencing:**

```
D2: =[@Consultant] & "-" & TEXT([@[Booking Date]],"dd/mm")  &"-" &COUNTIFS([@[Booking Date]]:INDEX([Booking Date],1),[@[Booking Date]],[@Consultant]:INDEX([Consultant],1),[@Consultant])
```

**With regular addressing:**

```
D2: =$C2 & "-" & TEXT($B2,"dd/mm")  &"-" &COUNTIFS($B2:INDEX($B:$B,2),$B2,$C2:INDEX($C:$C,2),$C2)
```

and fill down as far as needed

[image]

Comment: It's good one single formula solution +10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

*You need few Helper column to solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell AC 22:

  `=MONTH(Y22)&Z22`
- Formula in cell AB 22:

  `=COUNTIF($AC$22:AC22,AC22)`
- Final Formula in cell AA 22

  `=Z22&"-"&TEXT(Y22,"mm/dd")&"-"&AB22`

**N.B.**

- For neatness later on you may hide Helper Columnd.

[image]

- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help you @Faizan,,, since it's working for you so U may accept it as an answer as well up vote also,, [Check this,,](https://superuser.com/tour) ,, keep asking ☺